# Azure policy how do I have a field equal null?

Tags: azure-policy

How do I have a field equal null in an azure policy. I trying to have a policy that deny's having an email address empty. I was hoping that field equals null would work but it doesn't. below is what I have tried?
  

*{
"field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments/default.recurringScans.emails",
"equals": ""
 }*

Thanks
Russ

{
"field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments/default.recurringScans.emails",
"equals": ""
 }

Answer (score 1):

Policy doesn't have a null. You can try using notcontains and the wild card(*). See if that helps.